# Getting elasticsearch synonym work?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying a simple test on elasticsearch synonym without success, this is what I am so far

```
POST /mysearch
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" :   5,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0,
        "analysis": {
            "filter" : {
                "my_ascii_folding" : {
                    "type" : "asciifolding",
                    "preserve_original" : true
                },
                "my_stopwords": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": [ ]
                },
                "mysynonym" : {
                    "type" : "synonym",
                    "synonyms" : [
                        "foo => bar"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "char_filter": {
                "my_htmlstrip": {
                    "type": "html_strip"
                }
            }, 
            "analyzer": {
                "index_text_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "filter":       [ "lowercase", "my_stopwords", "my_ascii_folding" ]
                },
                "index_html_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "char_filter": "my_htmlstrip",
                    "filter":       [ "lowercase", "my_stopwords", "my_ascii_folding" ]
                },
                "search_text_analyzer":{
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer":    "standard",
                    "filter":       [ "mysynonym", "lowercase", "my_stopwords" ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "news" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : true },
            "_all" : {"enabled" : false},
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "store": "yes" , "analyzer": "index_text_analyzer" , "search_analyzer": "search_text_analyzer" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add some documnents

```
POST /mysearch/news
{
    "name":"foo kar"
}
POST /mysearch/news
{
    "name":"bar kar"
}
```

Do a search

```
POST /mysearch/_search?q=name:foo
{

}
```

Give me result that match `foo` , not `bar` , so why?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing it wrong, for the following reasons:

1. why do you use `foo => bar`? This means that you *replace* `foo` with `bar`, whereas if they are synonyms, they should be both indexed. So, I would use `foo,bar` instead.
2. why, at indexing time, you are using a different analyzer than at search time? At indexing time you will want your text to be indexed using its synonyms.

Let me give you an example: assuming you index `foo kar`. Since `bar` is a synonym of `foo` you'd want to index its synonym, as well, so that the index will contain `foo`, `bar`, `kar`. In this way, if you search for `foo` or `bar` that document WILL be found in the index even if the original text didn't contain `bar`.

These being said, I would suggest the following:

```
POST /mysearch
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_ascii_folding": {
          "type": "asciifolding",
          "preserve_original": true
        },
        "my_stopwords": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": []
        },
        "mysynonym": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "foo,bar"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_htmlstrip": {
          "type": "html_strip"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "index_text_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stopwords",
            "my_ascii_folding"
          ]
        },
        "index_html_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": "my_htmlstrip",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_stopwords",
            "my_ascii_folding"
          ]
        },
        "search_text_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "mysynonym",
            "lowercase",
            "my_stopwords"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "news": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "store": "yes",
          "analyzer": "search_text_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to index the synonyms, just indexing the original text and then, only at search time, search for the synonyms, as well, do the following changes:

- `"synonyms": ["foo,bar"]` because, as I mentioned above, you will replace `foo` with `bar` otherwise
- explicitly specify the two analyzers:

```
"index_analyzer": "index_text_analyzer",
"search_analyzer": "search_text_analyzer"
```

The two changes above will result in your text being indexed as is (with no synonyms), but at search time, when you want to search for `foo`, Elasticsearch will instead search for its synonym, as well: `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: yep, I want to make sure anonym is working as is. Until it's seem that elasticsearch was not care about `search_analyzer` defined as default in type (or in field level). The only way that make it work it set search_analyzer in the query, some guy talk about this https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3102 with version 0.9.0 but I still got it with 1.4.2

Comment: basically my index and search analyzer is the same, I just want to apply synonym in search phase.

Comment: Then use my second suggestion (change the way synonyms are defined and specifically mention index and search analyzer). Not sure why it doesn't use the `search_analyzer`... if the generic `analyzer` is specified...